# How to do something like this using xml in kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

[image]
I load data from the API, after which I need to display it as in this photo, the higher the value, the more the bar is filled in, the smaller the value, the less the bar is filled in. I looked for a solution on the internet, but didn't find anything like it. are there any solutions? :)

so now my stats look like this

[image] (size is not tied to value), how can i make it look like on the image above? (sorry if there is solution on stackoverflow already, i couldnot find it.

Comment: Post tyhe code you're using now.  I have some guesses on how you've implemented it (TextViews with a background image and border), but without knowing for sure we can't answer with how to fix it

Comment: yes, it is. just a textViews with data from response -
binding.idPokemonHp.text = "hp: ${it.stats[0].baseStat}"
binding.idPokemonAttack.text = "attack: ${it.stats[1].baseStat}"
etc.
any solutions?

Comment: Set a hardcoded width based on the value.  If the entire space is MAX_SIZE pixels, set the width to stat/max_stat_value * MAX_SIZE.  Alternatively, this would be a good use of a custom view and doing this with Canvas draw commands.

Comment: @GabeSechan thank you, i'll do research for Canvas class. So there's no alternative in xml for https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/value-based in composable, right?

Comment: That's compose.  It's an alternative to XML, not something that works with it